# How to compare strings in C++ and mergesort

Tags: c++, string, compare, mergesort

I am going to write a code which will compare some objects in array and sort them by name.

First of all how to compare strings in C++? In java it is easy oneString.compareTo(another);

If you are in posession of merge sort in C++ please share. Thank You!

Comment: Are you using `std::string`? You compare two strings the same way you compare builtin types like `int`. You simply use the comparison operators (`==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`).

Answer (score 1):

Comparing strings in C++ is very similar to in Java - the method is called `compare` instead of `compareTo`. So use `oneString.compare(another);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `std::string` member function `operator<()` as a comparison function for `std::sort` (using C++11 lambda expressions). This may or may not use merge sort as an implementation, but it will have the same `O(N log N)` complexity.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
        std::vector<std::string> v = { "foo", "bar" };

        std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

        std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](std::string const& elem) {
                std::cout << elem << "\n";
        });

        return 0;
}
```

Output on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/6sWR6)

Comment: You can replace that `std::lexicographical_compare` with a simple `s1 < s2`. In fact, the whole lambda is redundant since `std::sort`, by default, does a `less than` compare and `std::string` has `operator<` defined.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thanks! updated. I never really can remember what kind of operators `std::string` has built-in or not, so I just wrote the quickest thing that came to mind :-)

Comment: Your code was correct. I just didn't want @RobertKilar to think comparing strings needed to be complicated. Those other guys suggesting `std::string::compare` are nuts.